# Multiple isset with OR possibility

Tags: php

I'm trying to display items a specific way...

First I want to check if `$MYCAR_model` exists (this is a session value). If not, do nothing.

Next I want to make sure that the URL variable `cat` is set to either 1 or 2. If not, also do nothing.

The URL would look like this...

> http://www.mysite.com/?cat=1

My failed code...

```
if (isset($MYCAR_model) && ($cat=='1' || $cat=='2')) {

// show stuff
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: When you say "session value", do you mean `$_SESSION["MYCAR_model"]`? When you say "URL variable", do you mean `$_GET["cat"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['MYCAR_model']) && ($_GET['cat'] =='1' || $_GET['cat'] =='2')) {

// show stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much anthony. Much appreciated my friend. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
if (isset($_SESSION["MYCAR_model"]) ...
```

You can also use $_REQUEST["cat"] instead of $_GET["cat"] so that you don't need to worry about the parameter being passed via GET/POST/COOKIES.

Comment: Great info. Thank you Lucio!